# Trouble with Viewing Updates to Applet on my Website

Tags: java, upload, web, applet

So I have a website and I'm putting an Applet on it, and every so often, I update and re-upload that Applet. However, I cannot seem to view the changes I made to the Applet only. I am able to update and re-upload the index.html file, and I can view the change immediately, but It takes a day for me to be able to see the update I made to the Applet.

The odd thing is that my friends are able to see the change I made to the Applet immediately, so I know that the upload did work.

Yes, I have tried clearing my cache and restarting my browser, but that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) & flush the class cache, then refresh the page.

For more reliable and controllable updates, deploy the applet using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  For a better experience generally, deploy the app. as a `JFrame` using JWS.